# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for included project from Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

I have seen several questions and answers but i haven't find the answer. I don't know why I'm getting this exception, can you please help me?

Here is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qbe.android.ui.activity"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':AndroidDomain')
    compile project(':AndroidData')
    compile project(':AndroidCommon')
    compile project(':AndroidService')

    compile files('lib/crittercism_v5_5_1_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('lib/Android.Common-0.0.1.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
```

And here is my error log:

```
Process: com.android.ui.activity, PID: 15755
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.common.entity.DatoTPValor
     at com.qbe.android.ui.activity.FiltrosActivity.bindWidgets(FiltrosActivity.java:182)
     at com.qbe.android.ui.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:62)
     at com.qbe.android.ui.activity.FiltrosActivity.onCreate(FiltrosActivity.java:157)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I already try the gradle clean, gradle assemble, invalidate and restart cache, clean project, rebuild project, delete build project folders, and nothing works.

Hope you can help me

**UPDATE**

Here is the settings.gradle file:

```
include ':AndroidCommon'
include ':AndroidData'
include ':AndroidService'
include ':AndroidDomain'
include ':AndroidUI'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think that this is a gradle problem, or Android Studio. I delete the compile line of AndroidCommon from gradle, and I can deploy my app perfectly. It should fail, because the app uses this module, but doesn't fail. Do you have any ideas?

**UPDATE 3**

Well, I see that AndroidUI can interact with AndroidCommon, because if I create, for example, object "Dato", it can creates well. But if I crate DatoTPValor, it fails. And both "Dato" and "DatoTPValor" are in the same module. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

I don't know why, but the solution that works for me:

- I use a library (suppose library.jar) in AndroidCommon. In the build.gradle file of the module AndroidCommon, the dependency of that library was added ok.
- When I try to create an instance that inherit from a Class inside of library.jar, the app goes throw NoClassDefFoundError.
- I add library.jar to AndroidUI (the Android project) and add the dependency in the build.gradle file of AndroidUI project.
- Everything works ok.

Thank you all for your time and sorry for my bad english

Comment: which jar is this in `com.qbe.android.common.entity.DatoTPValor`?

Comment: Is in this project: ":QBEAndroidCommon"

Comment: did you specify your multiproject build config in the `settings.gradle` file in the root project dir?

Comment: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5 ????

Comment: I updated the post with the settings.gradle file. And the Java Version, I tried putting it to 1.6 and no result

Comment: you are not doing it right in the `settings.gradle` file. should just be like this `include ':QBEAndroidCommon', ':QBEAndroidData', ':QBEAndroidService', ':QBEAndroidDomain', ':QBEAndroidUI'`

Comment: Do you have all of your libraries open as modules within your Android Studio project? What is the directory structure of your projects?

Comment: @Dummy There are several ways to write the includes in the settings file. There is nothing wrong with OPs original approach.

Comment: @Henry, yeah, I've just checked Gradle's javadocs, I do admit you are right. I thought there was only one method taking a varargs, and I thought the later ones would just overwrite the previous ones. Bad part on me.